# How to remove duplicates from string list in python?

Tags: python, json, selenium

I need some help...
I'm new to python and I have a project, to crawl ad links from websites and save them in a JSON file to be used later in another script... All ad links have a form like this:

`https://domain/details.com?id=123456&pageNumber=1&len=en...`

The crawler joins every page to extract announcements and store them on a JSON file.
**The problem** : Already exist promoted announces, the promoted announces appear on every page on top, and  will be saved in a JSON file like this:

`{ https://domain/details.com?id=123456&pageNumber=1&len=en&searchId=93wsi-sais93-sdjs...`

`https://domain/details.com?id=283924&pageNumber=1&len=en&searchId=93wsi-sais93-sdjs...`

`... Other links from page 1 ...`

`https://domain/details.com?id=123456&pageNumber=2&len=en&searchId=si39-s9djw9-3jdss...}`

I need only unique announces...

The lop for generating links:

```py
links = []
for ad in dealersAd:
    href = ad.get_attribute("href")
    links.append(href)
```

Code for save links in JSON file:

```
# Save links in json file
dictionary =  {
    "Links" : links
}
json_dump = json.dumps(dictionary, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
# Create file and insert links
with open("../mobilede/mobilede selenium/src/links.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json_dump)
```

Is there some way to select the specific `?id=` from the link, analyze the id, and if already exist in the list, remove the link?

Thank's anticipated!

Comment: Hi, consider using regex or the in operator of string. What I mean is that you could somehow extract the ID from the href (by using string split by '?' character or using a regex to msche the id=. *?. This way you can add this id's to a list and use it to check whether the ID already exists or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can use set like this

```
new_menu = ['Hawaiian', 'Margherita', 'Mushroom', 'Prosciutto', 'Meat Feast', 'Hawaiian', 'Bacon', 'Black Olive Special', 'Sausage', 'Sausage']
```

final_new_menu = list(set(new_menu))

print(final_new_menu)

Comment: I know this method, to remove duplicates using set, I need to remove duplicates from id links because the IDs are the same but, the rest of the link is different